# Which online database is the best?

Tags: database

I search an online chess games database which should be free and it would be nice if no
 registration would be required.

I want to be able to search for the basic criterions year and ELO.

It would be nice if the database contains only classical games. It is annoying if
 rapid, blitz, blind and friendly games are also in the database.

Does anyone know a database fulfilling my criterions ?

Answer (score 2):

How about this website: http://database.chessbase.com/js/apps/database/

It's pretty good.

Comment: How do I search games ?

Comment: Theres an input box on the right side of the search board.

Comment: It seems that I cannot even search games without a registration. I could not find an input box, only a text-box. But at least some new games with strong players are listed by default.

Comment: In total, I am not convinced ...

Comment: When I mean't an input box, I mean't a text box, @Peter

Comment: But how does this help to find games ? I tried "2015" as an input and did nor find, as expected, games from 2015.

Comment: Try typing in Year 2015, @Peter

Answer (score 2):

chessgames.com because there are many comments on each game.  Has a good selection of top level games.

Answer (score 0):

Chesstempo.com has the best I have found for free online. 
https://chesstempo.com/game-database.html

Also has index by opening, player, and comments.
Plus other features.

If you will pay then chessbase is the best I have seen but I have not bought it to verify what it actually does have.